# Postgres: averaging a column on distinct of another column in already grouped query

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

Is there a way to average a column only on a distinct of another column when the query is already grouped for another purpose without using a subquery?  I know it can be done through subqueries, but trying to avoid restructuring an old query unless it is absolutely necessary.

The existing query, while complex, has more or less the same structure as the example below.  As you can see, a library has any number of books, a book has any number of chapters, and a chapter has any number of paragraphs while the query returns the total numbers of books and paragraphs for each library.

```
SELECT libraries.name,
 COUNT(DISTINCT books.id) AS num_books,
 COUNT(paragraphs.id) AS num_paragraphs
FROM libraries
LEFT JOIN books ON books.library_id = libraries.id
LEFT JOIN chapters ON chapters.book_id = books.id
LEFT JOIN paragraphs ON paragraphs.chapter_id = chapters.id
GROUP BY libraries.name
```

Now suppose the table *books* has a column *publish_year* and I want the average year books in the library were published.  Obviously I can't simply add *AVERAGE(books.publish_year)* since books with more chapters and paragraphs would skew the average.

Is there a good way of averaging *books.publish_year* based upon distinct *books.id* again without restructuring the query or is restructuring the query inevitable?

Answer (score 0):

A window function before joining

```
select
    l.name,
    count(distinct b.id) as num_books,
    count(p.id) as num_paragraphs,
    min(year_avg) as year_avg
from
    libraries l
    left join (
        select *, avg(publish_year) over(partition by library_id) as year_avg
        from books
    ) b on b.library_id = l.id
    left join chapters c on c.book_id = b.id
    left join paragraphs p on p.chapter_id = c.id
group by l.name
```

Comment: Oh okay, I see what you're doing here.  That should work for my example where *libraries* is the primary table.  How might this approach be applies if *books* was the primary table and *libraries* was left joined?

Comment: @IanBui This is the answer to the question you posted not to the one you did not. Make your mind up before posting and squandering other people time.

Comment: Umm, they're related.  I didn't realize that asking a followup question is considered "squandering" your time.